# Browser supoort for state object in popstate event?

Tags: javascript, dom-events, html5-history, popstate

I can find browser support for the `pushState` method but I know not all versions of browsers actually pass the state object in the `popstate` event. Is it something I can count on being able to use if the browser supports `pushState`?

Comment: Can you provide a link or a test-case that demonstrates the browser not passing the `state` object.

Comment: Unfortunately not, i just anecdotally recall developing this feature in an earlier version of firefox/chrome (1-2 years ago) and having to go entirely off the url because state was never passed.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend using [History.js](https://github.com/balupton/History.js/), which [normalizes](https://github.com/balupton/History.js/#notes-on-compatibility) the History API across browsers and even provides fallback mechanisims for older browsers that don't natively support the API.

Comment: Not sure I'm a big fan of there not being a popstate event with history.js and everything happening on changestate.

Comment: `window.onstatechange` *is* the normalized `window.onpopstate` event.